# Unobtrusive Data- Validation using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

I'm coming from [YouMightNotNeedjQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). I have been trying to find a way to add validation in my app without using jQuery. I am currently using ASP.Net Core MVC.

I can generate data-validations using this code from the model

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "Username must be at least 4 characters long.")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Which turns HTML like this: [Manually using MVC Client-Side Validation](http://www.blinkingcaret.com/2016/03/23/manually-use-mvc-client-side-validation/)

E.g. MaxLength

```
data-val-maxlength="Error message"
data-val-maxlength-max="Maximum length (e.g. 5)"
```

So my question is how can I achieve this with JavaScript? Is there any JavaScript library that is already available or do I have to make my own?

One way I can think of is, before a form submits, loop through each input that has a data-val and checks if it's valid or not. If not, return false and don't submit.

Comment: _Is there any library_? Yes, its `jquery-validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` (and they use jquery)

Comment: oh okay, thank you so much. Let me edit my question (:

Comment: I think there is something misunderstanding here. The attributes on your properties are rendered by asp.net and server responds the html with data validation attributes as you show. As @StephenMuecke mentioned by adding jquery-validate.js files will be enough for client-side validation, and these jquery codes looking for the tags generated by attributes, i suppose.

Comment: Yes, jquery is looking for these generated tags. My concern is, I am NOT using jquery on my project. Therefore, I was looking for an equivalent way of doing it without depending on jquery. Using plain JS.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it's still valid today. jQuery is huge and causes quite a drop in lighthouse performance scores just by its presence. There must be a non-jQuery option out there for this somewhere.

Comment: @Hades i can see the angular & react alternate sadly no vanilla js yet, maybe someone will have to write it or port from over these js frameworks/libs to plain script